# Retrieve last entered Nth row and display it in a signle cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have two excel sheets (Let's say Sheet1 and Sheet2). Sheet1 has a coloumnA in which I enter some values on daily basis. Each day I will receive 3 values each which will be entered in coloumnA.

For example: Sheet1.

```
                   ColoumnA

(cell 1) Day 1 ----> 1000
(cell 2)       ----> 2000
(cell 3)       ----> 3000
(cell 4) Day 2 ----> 1001
(cell 5)       ----> 2001
(cell 6)       ----> 3001
(cell 7) Day 3 ----> 1002
(cell 8)       ----> 2002
(cell 9)       ----> 3002
```

Sheet2 have three cells in which I will be again manually inputting these values on daily basis to prepare a daily report. And the previous day values will be replaced by the current day values. So I need Sheet2 to display these values automatically from Sheet1. So each cell in Sheet2 should fetch every 4th value and should replace the previous value with last entered date's value. Kindly show me how to achieve this with a formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming "Sheet1" has the following format:

```
Column A
Value 1
Value 2
Value 3
etc..
```

Then in Sheet 2 you can use the following formula to get the latest value for each of the 3 values:

```
Formula for value1: =IF(MOD(COUNTA(Sheet1!A:A);3)=0;INDEX(Sheet1!A:A;COUNTA(Sheet1!A:A)-2);INDEX(Sheet1!A:A;FLOOR(COUNTA(Sheet1!A:A);3)+1))
Formula for value2: =IF(MOD(COUNTA(Sheet1!A:A);3)>1;INDEX(Sheet1!A:A;COUNTA(Sheet1!A:A));INDEX(Sheet1!A:A;FLOOR(COUNTA(Sheet1!A:A);3)-1))
Formula for value3: =INDEX(Sheet1!A:A;FLOOR(COUNTA(Sheet1!A:A);3))
```

Note that the values will update while you add more values to "Sheet1"

Comment: Actually its not possible to rebuild as it is our company template format. Also the other columns have some other complex calculations which i didn't mentioned because it was not needed. Is it possible with the one i have?

Comment: I updated the answer. It got a little more complex, but hopefully it works for you.

Comment: Actually a small change needed first formula you gave to retrieve 3rd value, 2nd formula for 1st value and 3rd formula for 2nd value. But thank you very much. Worked like charm

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small vba macro that you can use.

```
Sub UpdateDataLastRows()
        Dim LastRow
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Select
        LastRow = Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, SearchOrder:=xlByRows).Row
        Range("A1") = CStr(LastRow)
        Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(2, 1) = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(CStr(LastRow) - 2, 1)
        Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(3, 1) = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(CStr(LastRow) - 1, 1)
        Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(4, 1) = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(CStr(LastRow), 1)
End Sub
```

You've to run this macro everytime you enter the data to update the Sheet2.
For ease of use, create one button and assign this macro to it.

Answer (score 0):

if you are sure that there are no blank rows in between data. 
you can use CountA function to know all 
=Counta(A:A) will give u non blank cell.

if you have blank cell in between : you can use vba function.

Function MyLastRow()
MyLastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
End Function

above function will only consider "A" column as data column.

Comment: Didn't get you. Can you explain how to use countA function in this case. I am not much of an excel expert.

Comment: download solution file from https://www.dropbox.com/s/xtg59utoil2p8mg/StackOverFlow1.xlsx?dl=0